# Fetching taxonomy as text

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to fetch taxonomy item(s) in my meta description tag but it add some hyperlink code in it.

I am using this code for that

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'writer', '', ', ' ); ?>
```

as

```
<meta name="description" content="These are the famous writers <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'writer', '', ', ' ); ?>. "/>
```

and the result that I want it this.

```
<meta name="description" content="These are the famous writers one, two, three" />
```

but I am getting this instead.

```
<meta name="description" content="These are the famous writers <a href="http://www.example.com/one">one</a>, <a href="http://www.example.com/two">two</a>, <a href="http://www.example.com/three">three</a>" />
```

So what can I do to get them without the hyperlink.

Comment: Use strip_tags() around get_the_term_list().

  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/get-the-term-list-without-links-in-3-1

Comment: Thanks to @gidomanders I found the solution as follows :

    <?php 
    $terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'writer', '', ', ' );
    $terms = strip_tags( $terms ); 
    echo $terms; ?>