# How to output Wordpress Taxonomy as text then use them as meta keywords?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags, taxonomy

I am creating functions to output Microdata for my posts. I want to use the taxonomy as `meta-keywords`, so I need to output them as text separated by commas.

I tried to follow the solution in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641584/fetching-taxonomy-as-text/), but no results came out at all.

First Attempt:

```
echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="';
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,', ' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );
echo $terms;
echo '"/>';
```

Second Attempt:

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,', ' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );
echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="';
echo $terms;
echo '"/>';
```

Third Attempt:

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,', ' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );
echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="';
$terms;
echo '"/>';
```

All attempts did not lead to any output at all. Can you please advise if there is a way to reach an output that looks like this:

```
<meta itemprop="keywords" content="category1,category2,tag1,tag2,tag3"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom fields instead of taxonomy. This is the right way to add the additional information to the wordpress site.

Please check below link.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: The idea I want to achieve is not to repeat adding the taxonomy again in another field manually. I already have a solution to add them as custom field, but this double work.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd attempt would never work because you have to use echo to print out the terms, but your first attempts were closer.

The problem is that you are not using  `get_the_term_list()` correctly. [See the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) - it only works for one taxonomy at a time, and you must pass in the name of the taxonomy you want to get the terms for.

You want to get all terms for all taxonomies, so first you need to get a list of all taxonomies, then you can use that list to get the terms.

I'd also suggest using `wp_get_post_terms()` because it can return the names without the  tags.

```
$term_names = array(); // array to store all names until we're ready to use them

// get all taxonomies for the current post
$taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies( $post );

foreach ($taxonomy_names as $taxonomy){      
    // get the names of all terms in $taxonomy for the post
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "names"));

    // add each term to our array
    foreach($term_list as $term){
        $term_names[] = $term;
    }
}

if ($term_names){ // only display the metatag if we have any terms for this page
    // implode will join all the terms together separated by a comma
    $keywords = implode(",", $term_names);
    echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="'.$keywords .'"/>';
}
```

I haven't tested that code so there might be a couple of problems, but let me know because the logic should work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I pasted the code. It did not break the website (so I believe there are no errors?) but when I checked the posts in the "Structured Data Testing Tool" from Google, it did not show any keywords at all. Is there a way to debug the code, as I am not good at php?

Comment: @AtefWagih the best way to debug php is to print out what its doing at each stage. So, I'd do a `var_dump()` after each step, i.e. `var_dump($taxonomy_names);` after you call `get_object_taxonomies`, `var_dump($term_list);` after `wp_get_post_terms`, etc. That way you can see whats working and where it stops. I've found the problem but it'd be good practice for you to try & see if you can find it. The best skill you can have as a developer is how to troubleshoot a problem! :-) Let me know when you find it and I'll tell you how to fix it (or if you don't find it I'll tell you where it is).

Comment: Thanks for helping me to e a better developer. I enabled the debug mode and added the `var_dump()` at each step, but all what I could see is a plugin using a deprecated function. So I'd appreciate it you tell me where is the problem in your code so I can use the function. Thanks :)

Comment: @AtefWagih The problem is that the line `$term_names[] = $term->name;` should have been `$term_names[] = $term;`. I've fixed it in the answer too. That's a strange thing for var_dump to do. It should just print the information directly to your webpage, i.e. not the console or testing tools. e.g. `var_dump($taxonomy_names);` should print the names of all the taxonomies for your page. I know you don't need it now, but it is very helpful to see whats in variables, it could save you hours trying to find a problem. Anyway, let me know if it works when you fix that line in your code!

Comment: @AtefWagih Did you get it to work with the updated code?